# Why is setAttribute giving me broken images from an array

Tags: javascript

I have created a dice game that can be played in the browser. Users can refresh the page to get a random dice roll. The dice with the most dots on it or the highest dice value win. Random dice images will be dynamically added to the src of the 2 image tags when the user click on refresh. All the coding logic is almost working, but however,   the dices images are broken  for some strange reason. I have been working on this coding challenge from Angela Yu Web Development Bootcamp on udemy for days. I'm using setAttribute to set the image's src to a random image from an array but it's not working.  Why are my images broken?

dices.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Refresh Me </h1>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 1</p>
        <img class="img1" src="">
      </div>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 2</p>
        <img class="img2" src="">
      </div>

    </div>
<script src="dice.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>

  <footer>
    www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
</html>
```

dice.js

```
function rollDice () {
  //two dices that will have 6 dots when game start. Same dice value
  document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "images/dice6.png");
  document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", "images/dice6.png");

  var highestDiceRoll = 0;
  var winner;

  var player1 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];

  var player2 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
  '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];


var randPlayer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length);
var randPlayer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length);

var diceRolls = player1[randPlayer1] + " " + player2[randPlayer2];


if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {

  // when page is refreshed, update image source to a random dice image
  document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", "randPlayer2");
  document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", "randPlayer2");

  if (randPlayer1 > randPlayer2) {
     highestDiceRoll = player1;
     winner = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player1 Won";
   } else if (randPlayer2 > randPlayer1) {
     highestDiceRoll = player2;
     winner = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player2 Won";
   } else {
     winner = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "DRAW";
   }
}

}
rollDice();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a simple case of assigning a string over a variable.
You added: `setAttribute("src", "randPlayer2");` when you should have
`setAttribute("src", player2[randPlayer2]);`

Update: I made a boo boo.

Also you'll need to refactor your `player1` & `player2` arrays. These have full html where they should only be like this for example:
`var player2 = ['images/dice1.png', 'images/dice2.png'];`

Using your code as you have it written with this small modification should work and won't require a complete rewrite.

Here is a full version without my commentary inbetween:

```
var player1 = ['images/dice1.png', 'images/dice2.png'];


var randPlayer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length);

function rollDice () {  
  //two dices that will have 6 dots when game start. Same dice value    
 document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", player1[randPlayer1]);  
}  
 rollDice()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the images array to urls only and set image as follows

```
var player2= ['images/dice1.png','images/dice2.png','images/dice3.png','images/dice4.png','images/dice5.png','images/dice6.png'];

...

document.querySelector(".img2").src = player2[randPlayer2];
```

same with player1

Answer (score 0):

```
 // when page is refreshed, update image source to a random dice image
  document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src", randPlayer2);
  document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src", randPlayer2);
```